# In MongoDB, can I create unsharded collection on each shard for $lookup?

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have been trying to use `$lookup` on mongos shards which isn't allowed.

If I create an unsharded collection, I know it is by default only created at primary shards. However, by using `$lookup` only from shards to primary shard is not efficient.

Therefore, what I have been thinking was to create the same collection on each shard then insert specifically on that shard using the same shard rule on config.

Then if I use `$lookup` from the sharded collection on the local collection, it will achieve my goal.

I was searching about this and found comments on this jira has the same issue [SERVER-29159](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-29159) as below.

[image: Comments on Jira]

Is there a way to achieve what I have just explained this?

From logical point of view, it should be achievable but the way to connect to shards is through routers so I believe unless mongodb offers such feature on routers, it is not possible... At least please tell me if it is not possible if you know mongo well.

P.S. I am using `spring-data-mongodb` as a client.

Comment: How do you ensure all of the shards have the same exact data at all times?

Comment: @D.SM No I don't have to ensure that. Shards will use hashing to distribute data and the collection to be joined should also use same hashing function to be on same shard

Comment: Are you saying you have come up with your own sharding implementation?

Comment: @D.SM Oh I was thinking there is a way to acquire how they distribute to each shard but maybe I was wrong. Is it not possible to do that? For example, if I use hashed digit for sharding configuration, can't I also use that to insert to specific shard?

Comment: You can request that mongodb places the data on a specific shard but if you are using mongodb's sharding all of your operations would be going through a mongos which as I understand won't allow you to unwind a sharded collection, for the reasons stated in the ticket. If you implement your own data mirroring you can query the data any way you like of course.

Comment: @D.SM It is a little late but thanks for your comment. I should just wait for the mongodb official support for querying $lookup on sharded collection :)